# Do I need APNS certificate as well as VOIP certificate?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, voip, pushkit

Our application is already registered for APNS. Since we are going to implement `PushKit`, we have created VOIP certificate too. Is it really necessary?
Can't we just use the APNS certificate for VOIP push?

Since there are two certificates now, I have to maintain two tokens. One is used to send normal push, and the other one to send VOIP push.

Can't we simply use one token/certificate for both purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use same certificate and device token for both simple push and VOIP Push. You must need to create separate certificates for both. Because both generates different device token which can't be used for one another.

Comment: But we can use the VOIP push token to send normal push right ?

Comment: No, You can't ! If you try to do it then it will work but it will not be simple push , all push will be VOIP push and will be handled in the respective delegate methods. This will directly execute the code written in didreceive method. And will not show you banner bcoz this is considered as silent push notification

Comment: Ah, ok i got your point. I know about silent pushes, just have to test once to make sure, anyway thanks for helping out :)

Comment: Your Welcome..! If you want to use VOIP for simple push then you will need to schedule local notification to show the banner.

Comment: Yes, i'm aware of that :)

Answer (score 12):

Actually you can use one universal certificate for your voip push and normal push.
When you send a normal push, use normal topic and normal token, which is generally your bundle identifier

> com.company.appname

When you send a voip push, use voip topic and your pushkit token, which is

> com.company.appname.voip

[See links in Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1)

Comment: Agree. Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's **possible** to use single certificate for both standard and VoIP pushes

Apple docs and portal is not so obvious and personally I spent lots of time to understand it

But what I can say for 100% sure is the following:

Actually you can create 3 types of certificates:

- Universal (for Production/Sandbox standard pushes + VoIP)
- Sandbox-only for standard pushes
- VoIP-only (for both Prod+Sandbox)

As you can see, you can create a single Universal certificate for **everything** and just simplify your life - just forget about separate Universal and VoIP certs.

Here is a cool guide I used to generate single Universal certificate which works everywhere https://developers.connectycube.com/ios/how-to-create-apns-certificate

Highly recommended. Personally I do not create separate Sandbox-only and VoIP certs anymore.

Comment: But still, we will have 2 difference codes to receive regular and VOIP notifications. And different device tokens to maintain?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to keep / maintain both certificates and both tokens, as APNS and VOIP certificates are totally different in purpose.

Pushkit payload with `'content-available'=> 1` will be silent notification and would not come in notification bar.

Reason is to keep both differently is "Some user may not want to register for VOIP feature" for particular app.

Check something needful [here](https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification).